# How to I add PILLOW library in Jython

Tags: python

i tried installing using "pip install Pillow" but i get an error
 "Invalid syntax.
Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal Jython."

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@Twirrim/thats-because-jython-doesn-t-support-pillow-349b41ae5b54

> That’s because Jython doesn’t support pillow. Pillow requires the multiprocessing module that isn’t available in Jython.

Doesn't look like its possible

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module is only used when building the shared libraries for Pillow. And even then it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [this wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo):

> Jython programs cannot currently use CPython extension modules written in C

Pillow is partially written in C, so it won't work on Jython.